# Python/Pandas comparing rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i need to compare data in two rows. You can find in image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNuey.png) the examples of valid rows.

My problem is that as you can see the rows arent always the same one by one. There is some diffences but, those differences doesnt matter for me.

The aim of my comparing is to if one row contain all the words/numbers that the second row.
Doesnt metter if one row have something more, like "assembly" or "E3" in exaple.
Comparing also should ignoring some characters like "/", ",",  "-" itd.

Could someone help with how to do it or modify my code.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNuey.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#df = (pd.read_excel("OA - Porownanie_20220420_1220.xlsx", "Export Worksheet", usecols="G, H"))
df = (pd.read_excel("VI - CompJob_Mapping_20220715_1244.xlsx", "JOBDESCID (OLD-NEW)"))

for i in range (0, 1148):
    try:
        a = df.iloc[i, 1]
        b = df.iloc[i, 2]
        x = a.split()
        y = b.split()

        data_1 = {'TYPE': x}
        data_2 = {'TYPE': y} 

        if np.array_equal(data_1, data_2):
            df.iloc[i, 3] = 'same'
        else:
            df.iloc[i, 3] = 'other'
    except:
        df.iloc[i, 3] = 'very bad'
df.to_excel("numtestresult.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

enter code here

I upload in my github some data examples with my comments what results I need.

https://github.com/mZadrzynski/Python_Data/blob/main/test.xlsx

Comment: Instead of pasting an image, please copy the text, and paste it, then format it as code

Comment: Might help to post an example of what your data looks like, and your expected output.